# can macro m4 support nested defined clause arguments

Tags: macros, m4

How I can use nested define unique argument?

```
define(`Honestly',`$1, define(`Does',`Iam$1')Does(Honest), $2')dnl

Honestly(Before, After)
```

actual result:

```
Before, IamBefore, After
```

Expected result:

```
Before, IamHonest, After
```

How Achieve the expected result ?

Answer (score 1):

Break up the `$1` token:

```
define(`Honestly',`$1, define(`Does',`Iam$'`1')Does(Honest), $2')dnl
Honestly(Before, After)
```

Comment: @mr.tee if it worked for you, please accept the answer (you earn +2 rep that way)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ticks around `define`:

```
define(`Honestly',$1-define(`Does',`Iam$1')Does(Honest)-$2)dnl
Honestly(Before, After)
```

Comment: Bad idea!! because you may have any commas "," there!! you will get the error "defined extra argument"

Comment: The `Honestly("Before,foo","After,baz")` works (replace the quotes to m4-quotes).